Intel Pin tool: Generating a single .trace file
I am using Intel Pin 3.21, and I am generating .trace files for one of my application.
I am generating around 1Billion instructions, and the tool automatically splits the output into multiple .trace files. Is there a way to generate the output in a single .trace file?
I tried manually combining 2 trace files in this manner:
cat output1.trace output2.trace > combined.trace

But I feel I can't manually combine like this, and when I use these combined.trace file, it doesn't work as expected
